# Reorder a sequence with minimum number of swaps to fulfil partial order constraints

Tags: algorithm, sequence, swap, inversion, partial-ordering

**Input:** An array of elements and a partial order on a subset of those elements, seen as a constraint set.

**Output:** An array (or any ordered sequence) fulfilling the partial order.

**The Problem:** How can one achieve the reordering efficiently? The number of introduced inversions (or swaps) compared to the original input sequence should be as small as possible. Note, that the partial order can be defined for any amount of elements (some elements may are not part of it).

**The context:** It arises from a situation in 2-layer graph crossing reduction: After a crossing reduction phase, I want to reorder some of the nodes (thus, the partial order may contain only a small subset).

In general, I had the idea to weaken this a little bit and solve the problem only for the elements being part of the partial order (though I think, that this could lead to non-optimal results). Thus, if I have a sequence A B C D E and the partial order only contains A, B and E, then C and D will stay at the same place. It somehow reminds me of the Kemeny Score, but I couldn't yet turn that into an algorithm.

Just to be sure: I am not searching for a topological sort. This would probably introduce a lot more inversions than required.

**Edit 1:**

- Changed wording (sequence to array).
- The amount of additional space for solving the problem can be arbitrary (well, polynomially bounded) large. Of course, less is better :) So, something like O(ArrayLen*ArrayLen) at most would be fantastic.
- Why the min amount of swaps or inversions: As this procedure is part of crossing reduction, the input array's ordering is (hopefully) close to an optimum, in terms of edge crossings with the second node layer. Then, every additional swap or inversion would, probably, introduce edge crossings again. **But** in the process of computing the output, the number of swaps or movements done is not really important (though, again, something linear or quadratical would be cool), as only the output-quality is important. Right now, I require the constraints to be in a total order and only inspect the nodes of that order, thus it becomes trivial to solve. But the partial order constraints would be more flexible.

Comment: So you have an array and not a list? E.g. If you have ABCDE and partial order CEA then with a list the most efficient thing would be to just move A to the end.

Comment: nice problem. slightly under specified though. first, the term "sequence" is vague (as you can see from the previous comment). is it an array or list or some other data structure? second, are you allowed to use additional memory (for something like doing a side "sorting", deciding what swaps to make, then performing them on the initial sequence)? third, why swaps (though this might be obvious if one is familiar with "the context", which I am not)? and why minimize their number, are they expensive?

Comment: Whew, I should have wait for answers before sleeping :) @maraca: In this special case, maybe this would be a good solution. But did you use kind of an efficient algorithm to solve it?

Comment: @cobarzan: Answers in my edit, thank you.

Comment: I think you probably are looking for a topological sort, or at least a variation thereof.  I would suggest using ordinary topological sort, but with the following twist: always pick the *earliest* vertex that has no predecessors.  (This means using a priority queue instead of the usual DFS.)

Comment: Actually, that does sound promising. I was so fixed to some Kemeny related solution, that I totally refused to at least consider any variation of topological sort. I will look further into that, thank you!

Comment: You're welcome :)  BTW, if you want someone to be notified of your comment, include their username like so: @j_random_hacker.  (Only works for 1 per comment, mind you.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a paper, which looks promising: "A Fast and Simple Heuristic for Constrained Two-Level Crossing Reduction" by Michael Foster.
Together with the comments below my question, it is answered. Thanks again, @j_random_hacker!